# Manage Hyperledger Composer wallet

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have been trying to connect my Hyperledger composer to my bluemix instance with no visible result. in the process I accidentally did rewrite my admin account with a different password.

Since there is no visual way seemingly to control the users in the wallet my question is: is there any way to manager the users inside a hyperledger composer wallet?

Comment: What kind of things do you envisage you would need to do with a wallet ?

Comment: Remove a credential or update a current one

Comment: The Wallet api supports those operations but I think there is more work to be done to make the wallet implementations more capable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to visually manage wallets in the playground, other than to issue or add new identities.

The playground just uses local storage for identities in your wallet at the moment so, if it starts causing problems, you could try using a private browser window. (A different browser or entering `localstorage.clear()` in the browser console should also give you an empty wallet).

There are some ideas around for expanding identity management in the future. Have a look at [issue 817](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/817) in the [hyperledger composer repository](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer) if you're interested in finding out more.